# How to model tf-idf spark

Tags: pyspark, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I'm trying to re-write a code wrote (that it's in Python), but now in spark.

```
#pandas
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer() 
df_final = np.array(tfidf.fit_transform(df['sentence']).todense())
```

I read on spark documentation, is it necessary to use Tokenizer, HashingTF and then IDF to model tf-idf in PySpark?

```
#pyspark

from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, IDF, Tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol = "sentence", outputCol = "words")
wordsData = tokenizer.transform(df)
hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol = "words", outputCol="rawFeatures", numFeatures = 20)

tf = hashingTF.transform(wordsData)
idf = IDF(inputCol = "rawFeatures", outputCol = "features")
tf_idf = idf.fit(tf)

df_final = tf_idf.transform(tf)
```

Comment: I believe your spark example is copied directly by the spark official example, what is the question that you're trying to solve or what do you mean by necessary or not? Could you explain more about your question?

Comment: You're right :) I just want to know if it is the most correct way to implement tf-idf (python's lib to pyspark's lib). For example, I didn't understand why I needed a Tokenizer on pyspark whay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you understand clearly how `tf-idf` model works, since tokenizing is essential and fundamental for `tf-idf` model no matter in `sklearn` or `spark.ml` version. You post actually cover 2 questions:

1. Why `tf-idf` need to tokenization the `sentence`: I won't copy the mathematical equation since it's easy to search in google. Long in short, `tf-idf` is a statistical measurement to evaluate the relevancy and relationship between a word to a document in a collection of documents, which is calculated by the how frequent a word appear in a document (`tf`) and the inverse frequency of the word across a set of documents (`idf`). Therefore, as the essence is the vocabulary and all calculation are based on vocaulary, if your input is `sentence` like what you mentioned in your `sklearn` version, you must do the tokenizing of the sentence before the calculation, otherwise the whole methodology is not valid anymore.
2. How `tf-idf` work in `sklearn`: If you understand how `tf-idf` works, then you should understand the different steps in the example of `spark` official document are essential. Thanks for the `sklearn` developer to create such convenient API, you can use the `.fit_transform()` directly with the Series of `sentence`. In fact, if you check the source code of the `TfidfVectorizer` in sklearn, you can see that it actually did the "tokenization", just in a different way:

   1. It inherits the from the `CountVectorizer` (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/36958fb240fbe435673a9e3c52e769f01f36bec0/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L1717)
   2. It uses the `._count_vocab()` method in `CountVectorizer` to transform your sentence. (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/36958fb240fbe435673a9e3c52e769f01f36bec0/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L1338)
   3. In `._count_vocab()`, it checks each sentences and create the sparse matrix to store the frequency of each vocabulary in each sentences before the `tf-idf` calculation. (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/36958fb240fbe435673a9e3c52e769f01f36bec0/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L1192)

To conclude, tokenizing the `sentence` is essential for the `tf-idf` model calculation, the example in `spark` official documents is efficient enough for your model building. Remember to use the function or method if `spark` provide such API and DON'T try to build the user defined function/class to achieve the same goal, otherwise it may reduce your computing performance or trigger other issue like out-of-memory.